# How to instantly reflect change in value on Checkbox change ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am stuck for 1 full day on this. I want when the checkbox is checked, the value of 'Done' changes as planned below. Please help me as I am learning this.  Tried using usestate but it cant work. The method I used below is a mutable method and I learnt it doesnt work in react. I tried using setTodo to set the object but it gives an entirely diferent thing. Here is the link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-lederberg-39ub6v?file=/src/App.js

Below is my code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import {useState} from 'react'
import Addtask from './Addtask'

export default function App() {

 
  const dataset = [
                  {key:'', id: 1, title: 'Go to School', done: 'false'},
                  {key:'', id: 2, title: 'Go to Gym house', done: 'false'},
                  {key:'', id: 3, title: 'Go to Market', done: 'false'},
                  {key:'', id: 4, title: 'Go to Stadium', done: 'false'},
                  {key:'', id: 5, title: 'Go to Podium', done: 'false'},
                ]

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(dataset)
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState('')


  
  const todolist = todos.map(singletodo => {

      return (
        
        <ul style={{paddingBottom: '1em'}}>
        <li> 
        <span><input type='checkbox'  
        onChange={(e) =>  {
          if(e.target.checked){
          alert('hello')
          singletodo["done"] = 'true'
          }else {
            alert('nooooo')
            singletodo["done"] = 'false'

          }
      }  }/><label> Completed </label>

        </span>
        </li>
        <li>Title: {singletodo.title}</li>
        <li>ID: {singletodo.id}</li>

        <li>Done: {singletodo.done}</li>
       <hr></hr><li> <button onClick ={()=> setTodos(todos.filter(bad => bad.key !==singletodo.key))} style={{float: 'left', }}>delete</button> 
       
        <button style={{float: 'right',}}>edit</button></li>
        </ul>)
 
  });


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <Addtask data ={todo} list = {todos} settodo = {setTodo} settodos ={setTodos}/>
      {todolist}

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: please append your codesandbox link to question

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-lederberg-39ub6v?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

In React, when you want to update an array that is being tracked in state, you not only need to update the array, but also call `setTodos` on it.

Once you've updated the array itself with the changes you want to make(inside the onChange). Then, you need to call the `setTodos` method and pass in the updated array as a parameter.

```js
if (e.target.checked) {
  alert('hello');
  singletodo["done"] = 'true';
} else {
  alert('nooooo');
  singletodo["done"] = 'false';
}
setTodos(prevTodos => {
  const updatedTodos = prevTodos.map(todo => {
    if (todo.id === singletodo.id) {
      return singletodo;
    }
    return todo;
  });
  return updatedTodos;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked very well, however I feel bad that I don't understand what you actually did. I am new to do and understand I need to study more. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! Don't worry about not understanding everything at first - learning new concepts takes time and practice. Reading up on array methods and practicing using them will definitely help you become more comfortable with working with arrays in JavaScript. Keep learning and stay cheerful!

Answer (score 0):

i edited your code :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const dataset = [
    { key: "", id: 1, title: "Go to School", done: "false" },
    { key: "", id: 2, title: "Go to Gym house", done: "false" },
    { key: "", id: 3, title: "Go to Market", done: "false" },
    { key: "", id: 4, title: "Go to Stadium", done: "false" },
    { key: "", id: 5, title: "Go to Podium", done: "false" }
  ];

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(dataset);

  const setDoneForTodo = (isDone, index) => {
    setTodos((todos) =>
      todos.map((todo, i) => {
        if (index === i) {
          return { ...todo, done: isDone ? "true" : "false" };
        } else {
          return todo;
        }
      })
    );
  };

  const todolist = todos.map((singletodo, index) => {
    return (
      <ul style={{ paddingBottom: "1em" }} key={index}>
        <li>
          <span>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={(e) => {
                if (e.target.checked) {
                  setDoneForTodo(true, index);
                } else {
                  setDoneForTodo(false, index);
                }
              }}
            />
            <label> Completed </label>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>Title: {singletodo.title}</li>
        <li>ID: {singletodo.id}</li>

        <li>Done: {singletodo.done}</li>
        <hr></hr>
        <li>
          {" "}
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              setTodos(todos.filter((bad) => bad.key !== singletodo.key))
            }
            style={{ float: "left" }}
          >
            delete
          </button>
          <button style={{ float: "right" }}>edit</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {todolist}
    </div>
  );
}
```

please check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-banach-00dkwz?file=/src/App.js:0-1851)

you need use `setState` for updating `state` ,
in this case use `setTodos` for `todos` state! :

```
const setDoneForTodo = (isDone, index) => {
    setTodos((todos) =>
      todos.map((todo, i) => {
        if (index === i) {
          return { ...todo, done: isDone ? "true" : "false" };
        } else {
          return todo;
        }
      })
    );
  };
```

Comment: This worked too , though I can't grasp my head around the code. I will learn more of this. Thank you